# Can my tomato plant move indoors?

Tags: houseplants, tomatoes

I have a potted tomato plant on my porch. The temperature is starting to drop as we move into fall; will it adapt well to being an indoor plant? My windows don't get a ton of sun I'm afraid. The plant is about four feet tall, of the variety "Watermelon Beefsteak". It's got a few flowers that are just starting to develop fruits; will this be interrupted if I bring it inside? Should I bring it in now or wait until it gets cold properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not come up with a good reason why you couldn't, but depending on size, soil, inside temp/sunlight, ect, it could be a bad idea.  Also of interest is your location.  If it was me I would try, but I would not expect a good outcome.  On a plus side if it did do well you would have a great start next year.

I do have a couple of suggestions.  I have an acquaintance who has a very large hydroponic greenhouse in Kentucky.  He told me that the important things for tomatoes is temperature, water, and nutrients.  So I would use a balanced miracle grow type product, keep it well, but not overly watered, and most of all WARM.  According to him, light was not as important to tomatoes as heat.

I hope that it helps some.
-Bruce

Sorry I almost forgot all about my last thought: Prune the sucker vines!!  They take too much energy from the rest of the plant.  I'm sure you can find some Google some good info on how to ID and prune sucker vines on tomato plants.  Good Luck -Bruce

Answer (score 4):

You can move a tomato indoors, but the problem will be that it will grow spindly and thin, crawl along the ground, and will not set new fruit. Existing fruit won't ripen quickly.  But if it survived until Spring you would probably get tomatoes starting in April/May depending on your climate.